# how to handle cid image sources when rendering emails in iframe

Tags: javascript, email, iframe, exchangewebservices, embedded-resource

we have a web-email-client written in Angular4+.
We load the emails from an Exchange web service.

Incomming mails are sanitized and then rendered as source to an iframe.
This works fine even with images except they are embedded as like

```
<img width="486" height="572" id="Grafik_x0020_2" src="cid:image002.jpg@01D39103.BD805530">
```

Is there a way to show the images when rendering the email?
We are able to download attachments as well.

Thanks and best regards
Christoph

Answer (score 5):

as we already download the attachments I wrote a pipe that solves the problem:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TrusthtmlPipe } from 'app/crm-modules/core/pipes/trusthtmlPipe';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service';
import { AttachmentInfo } from 'app/crm-modules/email/models/attachment-info';

import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Pipe({
  name: 'cidToBase64'
})

export class CidToBase64Pipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
  }

  transform(html: any, attachments: Array<AttachmentInfo> = []): SafeHtml {
    let htmlToParse;
    if (typeof html === 'string') {
      htmlToParse = html;
    } else if (html instanceof Object && html.hasOwnProperty('changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity')) {
      htmlToParse = (html.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity !== null || html.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity !== undefined)
        ? html.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity
        : '';
    } else {
      htmlToParse = '';
    }

    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlToParse, 'text/html');

    if (attachments !== null && attachments !== undefined && attachments.length > 0 && htmlToParse.length > 0) {
      const imageLinks = doc.getElementsByTagName('img');
      for (let i = 0; i < imageLinks.length; i++) {
        const imageLink = imageLinks[i];
        const src = imageLink.getAttribute('src');
        if (src !== null && src !== undefined && _.includes(src, 'cid:')) {

          let cidInfo;
          let fileName;
          let fileIndex;
          let useImage = true;

          cidInfo = src.split('cid:');
          useImage = cidInfo.length === 2;

          if (useImage) {
            fileName = cidInfo[1].split('@')[0];
            fileIndex = _.findIndex(attachments, { 'name': fileName, 'inline': true });
            useImage = fileIndex > -1;
          }

          if (useImage) {
            imageLink.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + attachments[fileIndex].content);
          } else {
            // @todo: show placeholder or remove the node...
          }
        }
      }
    }

    const trustHtmlPipe = new TrusthtmlPipe(this.sanitizer);
    return trustHtmlPipe.transform(doc.documentElement.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

Maybe it helps.

Best regards
Christoph

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your code. I rewrote your pipe to use it myself, I think it is a little more generic so I leave it here in case someone finds it useful:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'cidToBase64'
})

export class CidToBase64Pipe implements PipeTransform {

  parser : DOMParser = new DOMParser();

  constructor() {
  }

  transform(html: String, attachments: Attachment[]): String {

    if (html.length <= 0) {
      return "";
    }
    if (attachments == null || attachments == undefined || attachments.length < 0) {
      return "";
    }

    const doc = this.parser.parseFromString(html.toString(), 'text/html');
    const imageLinks = doc.getElementsByTagName('img');

    for (let i = 0; i < imageLinks.length; i++) {
      const src = imageLinks[i].getAttribute('src');
      if (src !== null && src !== undefined && src.includes('cid:')) {
        let attachmentContent = src.split('cid:')[1].split('@')[0];
        let fileIndex = attachments.findIndex(obj => obj.Name === attachmentContent);
        imageLinks[i].setAttribute('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + attachments[fileIndex].Content);
        html = html.replace(src, imageLinks[i].getAttribute('src'));
      }
    }
    return html;
  }
}

export interface Attachment {
  Content: String;
  ContentLength: Number;
  Name: String;
  ContentType: String;
  ContentID: String;
}
```

You can then use it in your .html as any other pipe:

```
<p [innerHTML]="mail.HtmlBody | cidToBase64 : mail.Attachments"></p>
```